# MVC Dropdownlist returns null to HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

My problem is that I am trying to setup a drop down list and when a new item is selected it will update a table of information that I have but every time HttpPost function gets called the parameter is always null. Here is index function of my home controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   Project[] projects = db.Projects.ToArray();
   List<SelectListItem> dropList = new List<SelectListItem>();
   BurndownSprintTable[] TableToShow = db.BurndownSprintTables.ToArray();

   for (int index = 0; index < projects.Length; ++index)
        {
            dropList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = projects[index].Name, Value = projects[index].Id.ToString(), Selected = projects[index].Selected });
            if (projects[index].Selected == true)
            {
                int ProjectId = projects[index].Id;
                TableToShow = db.BurndownSprintTables.Where(x => x.ProjectId == ProjectId).ToArray();
            }
        }
  ViewBag.Projects = dropList;
  return View(TableToShow);
}
```

TableToShow is used to show sprint information per project.

Here is the post function:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProjectUpdate(string strProjectId)
    {
      return View("Index");
    }
```

I realize this post function will cause an error which I believe I can fix on my own but I need strProjectId to not be null.

Here is the html:

```
@model IEnumerable<TableauConfigWebService.Models.BurndownSprintTable>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectUpdate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<h5>@Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)

<input type="submit" value="Update" /></h5>
}
```

There is more to it but the rest of the html is setting up a table for the sprint information which works fine.

I have looked around and found a bunch of posts on this but none of them seem to help. I am new to mvc so I know its probably something simple but I cant figure it out.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: string strProjectId in the parameter should be the same as dropdown list Id that looks like "Id". MVC map the values in the httppost control based on the Id/name given to the html control

Comment: Well that was really simple. Thanks this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
         [HttpPost]
           public ActionResult ProjectUpdate(string Id)
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }
```

Or change the control Name to

```
      @Html.DropDownList("strProjectId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way , and check it ,

> Must be same names are dropdown and model property .

But you can try this simple way

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProjectUpdate()
    {
     **string strProjectId=Request.Form["strProjectId"].ToString();**//Or use Request["strProjectId"].ToString();
      return View("Index");
    }

@Html.DropDownList("**strProjectId**", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)
```

or

Simply, you can use *FormCollection* like,

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProjectUpdate(FormCollection collection)
        {
         **string strProjectId=collection["strProjectId"].ToString();**
          return View("Index");
        }

    @Html.DropDownList("**strProjectId**", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)
```

And check my code with using break points !

Answer (score 0):

Use the same parametre name at both the place in view and controller.

either change in controller.

```
public ActionResult ProjectUpdate(string Id)
    {
      return View("Index");
    }
```

or else change in view dropdown code to this.

```
@Html.DropDownList("strProjectId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)
```

hope this helps...